# When printing a Access Report that's open in Preview, why is it printing contents of a table?

Tags: ms-access, printing

I have a report Open in Print Preview mode. I have accomplished this using a button with the code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNameHere", acViewPreview, "", "", acNormal
```

When I print using Ctrl+P, the report prints as expected. When I go to File>Print however, it sends the contents of a table to the printer. The table it prints is currently selected in the Navigation Pane, and the program is for some reason ignoring the currently open window. This happens for each different report that I open in this same manner.

Is there anyway to fix this behavior? This database will be distributed in .accde format with the Navigation Pane hidden. That particular table will always be selected by default because it is the top object in the pane.

I'm guessing the answer is one of three options: 1) When I Open a report using my On-Click event, some sort of code to also select it in the Navigation Pane; 2) An option or code somewhere that will force the program to print the open window and not the selected table; 3) A way to remove the Print entry from the File menu so the only option is for users to print with Ctrl+P.

Edit: Using Access 2016, which may make a difference. I've also confirmed this happends regardless of what is currently selected in the Navigation Pane, that item is what is sent to the printer.

Edit 2: I think this has to do with my Forms/Reports that have the "Pop Up" set to Yes. For any of those, the problem occurs. Whenever "Pop Up" is set to No, it does not.

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. The report prints for me even though table shows highlighted in Navigation Pane. However, I don't see an `acNormal` parameter, it is `acWndowNormal`. I am using Access 2010.

Comment: Updated the question to specify I'm using Access 2016 in case it matters. I changed the parameter to acWindowNormal to see if it affected anything but saw no change.

Comment: More information I've learned is that this only appears to happen for Forms/Reports that have the Pop Up parameter set to Yes. It seems like File>Print ignores these being open. Don't suppose this is behavior that can be changed?

Comment: Nope. Don't use Popup for report. I never have. I also always set db for Overlapping Windows instead of Tabbed Documents.